# Properly exit a wpf plugin for Revit

Tags: c#, wpf, plugins, exit, revit

I'm working on a plugin for Revit. Revit permits only dll type addins and I chose c# and wpf for gui. I couldn't initialize wpf natively so I needed to contain it in a system.windows.window as content. 
Now if I close that window with upper right X program continues (looping processing etc.) it doesn't get terminated. Window.close() again just closes the window not the application it self.
How should I exit my app and not keep it lurking in the shadows?

```
[Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Transaction(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.TransactionMode.Manual)]
public class FDNMain : IExternalCommand
{
    public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData CommandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
    {
        FDNControl wpfControl = new FDNControl();
        return Result.Succeeded;
    }
}
```

Above is the Revit external command class which cannot initialize (show up) the wpfControl. So I need to wrap the wpfcontrol with a System.Windows.Window as below:

```
Window hostWindow = new Window();
hostWindow.Content = wpfControl;
hostWindow.Show();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I couldn't initialize wpf natively"?

Comment: I've added the externalcommand class to the post which cannot initialize the wpf user control directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined global static variable which is set to true while host window is closing. And set this condition to be check in the while statement in order the loop to be continued. such as:

```
...
    Global.hostWindow.Closing += hostWindow_Closing;
...

    private void hostWindow_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Global.Closing = true;
    }
...

    while (Nodes.Count > 0 && Global.Closing == false)
    {
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I see. There is no XAML Window template in Visual Studio for a class library, but you can create an UserControl as you did and then change the `UserControl` tag in your XAML to a `Window` one.

You also need to change it in the .xaml.cs (you can also remove it, because it is a partial class and the parent class is implicit with the XAML). After that, you will be able to call `ShowDialog` on your window.

Comment: Ok, I've switched from xaml to window but It didn't cure the issue of app not shutting down. It also rendered the revit ui unreachable while my app window is active. So I'd stick with xaml inside the window.
However I found out that the main problem is that I'm using dispatcher.invoke method to keep a progressbar responsive while inside a long process loop. Afaic that method keeps the app running in the background even if I click close.
How can I detect the cancelation and break the main loop?